# UISplitView Ipad custom search bar

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I wants to add (custom bar) a search bar and 3 buttons on UISplitView bar, It is possible? please direct me in right way. any tutorial or link really appriciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you done any tutorials about building UIs in interface builder or using storyboards?

Comment: yes, i read and implement from this link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPad_iOS_5_Split_View_and_Popover_Example#About_the_Example_iPad_Split_View_and_Popover_Project

Comment: +1 for you, I don't know why you down voted, you can simply hide the navigation bar and place a toolbar upside in your desired xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag a UIToolBar at the top of desired xib and First drag the BarButtonItem then drag the search bar into it..and finally another barbuttonItem  to get your desired custom Bar

Comment: I wants to hide default UISplitView bar and make custom bar in place of it, it's possible ?

Comment: if thats the case...Add the following line of code to the DetailViewController's viewWillAppear... [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];